# Upgrade Couchbase fail from 2.0.1 to 2.1.1

Tags: couchbase

I'm having this upgrade issue and I'm not sure how to move forward with it.  I have 2 couchbase servers, server 1 and server 2.  both in couchbase community 2.0.1. I brought the server 2 down and do the couchbase upgrade to 2.1.1.  Upgrade successful but then I can't restart the couchbase eventhough I rebooted already.  Also for some reason after upgrade the chkconfig for couchbase disappear.  Found out that there's a bug for that particular issue so I ended up having to reinstall the whole couchbase server for server 2.  No biggy.  Installation successful.  However when I tried to rejoin the cluster, server 2 gave me this error

```
Attention - Got no response from save request.
```

I'm sensing its because server 1 is still in 2.0.1 and it wouldn't let new server 2 with 2.1.1 connect to it.  Or is there a different issue?  Anyone has ever went through this upgrade process with the same issue and has a solution for it?

I then tried to restore using the file base restore by copying the whole folder back to its original location. Couchbase server 2 can't be started now. 1 thing I just found out. Config.dat is not in the location where I have all the folders. and I found it somewhere else in /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat. So what that means that config.dat didn't get backed up. Am I pretty much SOL for Server 2? Or can I just copy the config.dat from server 1?

Please help?

FYI.  Both my servers are on Centos 6.4 64 Bit.